# Cannot open pdf form on Ubuntu 14.4

Tags: pdf, forms, ubuntu-14.04

While trying to open a pdf form, it raised an error and refused to open the form all together.

It displays:

**Please wait...**
If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDF
viewer may not be able to display this type of document....."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what application you are trying to use (and I can't comment to clarify due to lack of reputation) to open the PDF form but if you are not using Adobe Reader, maybe you can try it out.

User "hanzj" over the Ubuntu forums gave a link to the PDF he had similar problems with (same error message) and user "kimberlite" claims to have been able to open the file using Adobe Reader. ([Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2059503))

Here's a link on how to install Adobe Reader in Ubuntu 14: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-adobe-reader-ubuntu-1404/

EDIT: Added link to tutorial

Comment: Thanks [ThePracticalHacker]. I tried to see the links you suggested, but the operating system I am using is not in the list.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @SisayAdugna. I've edited my answer to include a tutorial for installing Adobe Reader on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution that worked for me from [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-adobe-reader-ubuntu-1404/). After running the following commands, the issue is resolved. However, my computer is complaining because I used third party repositories.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ raring partner" 
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install acroread libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 lib32nss-mdns* libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```